# Saving changed variables between runtime Rust

Tags: rust

Is there an elegant way to save a variable/s so that a state is reflected between executions. I think reading and updating a config file (yaml) is a pretty good solution but for just a couple of variables it seems a bit of a hastle. Any thoughts?

Comment: What you are describing is an operation called "serialization" (for the saving part) and "deserialization" (for restoring the state). Luckily, Rust has a very good SERialization DEserialization crate called serde (I'll let you guess why), which can use several backends (that is, you can the variables in a variety of formats).

Comment: @BlackBeans yes i have looked into serde but i don't think that serialization itself keeps values between runtime. My question really is the best way to access and save serialized values. Is an external file the only way?

Comment: @BlackBeans I don't completely agree with your statement, 'serialization' and 'deserialization' are the conversions of structured data into a bytearray based representation. The actual persistance comes from storing that bytearray somewhere, like in a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misuse term `runtimes`, I think what you mean is `executions`. But I think I get what you are trying to ask. This is not Rust-specific. Executables in general are stateless, they do not store any information between executions.

So if you want to persist state between executions, you need to store it somewhere. The options are many. The most common ones are files or databases.

If it's really just a couple of variables the easiest way would probably be `json` via the awesome [`serde_json`](https://crates.io/crates/serde_json) library. With it, you can convert normal Rust structs into human readable ASCII text and store it in file.

You could even wrap it in a struct that can load/store the state.
Although you have to be careful with concurrent access then.

Here is a somewhat simple example of a struct that can persists its state in a file:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::{fs::File, io::BufReader, path::Path};

const STATE_FILENAME: &'static str = "state.json";

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct PersistentState {
    counter: u32,
}

impl PersistentState {
    fn load() -> Self {
        let path = Path::new(STATE_FILENAME);
        if path.exists() && path.is_file() {
            let file = File::open(path).unwrap();
            serde_json::from_reader(BufReader::new(file)).unwrap()
        } else {
            Self::default()
        }
    }

    fn store(&self) {
        let file = File::create(STATE_FILENAME).unwrap();
        serde_json::to_writer(file, self).unwrap();
    }
}

impl Default for PersistentState {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self { counter: 0 }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut state = PersistentState::load();

    state.counter += 1;
    println!("Counter: {}", state.counter);

    state.store();
}
```

First execution:

```
Counter: 1
```

Second execution:

```
Counter: 2
```

`state.json` file:

```
{"counter":2}
```

Of course don't just copy-paste the code into your project but instead think about your usecase and adapt it to your needs.

---

### Pitfalls

Not all types are losslessly storable in `json`. Most are, like strings, integers and booleans, but **floats are not**. Floats are stored in human readable decimal, but handled in binary, and there is always a small rounding error in the conversion. But unless you are doing scientific calculations, that is most likely irrelevant.

If you don't like `json`, `serde` supports a bunch of [other types](https://serde.rs/#data-formats) as well.

Comment: Thanks for the through response, answered the question, need to store changed valued in external files between executions.

Comment: I'm not too keen on implementing Drop to do some IO stuff. That seems dangerous.

Comment: @BlackBeans I agree. Will rewrite.

Comment: @BlackBeans better?